# Confused about how to handle line endings in git repo

Tags: git, line-endings

I have some *basic* knowledge about `core.autocrlf` and `text` in `.gitattributes` Still I had stuck with my scenario.

**Scenario**

In all my editors I use CR LF, so when I modify a file it will be saved with CR LF endings. However I must regularly update files in my repo from *external* source (I mean copy over) and those files are using LF line endings.

**What I've tried**

I thought `core.autocrlf=true` will work for me, but unfortunately here is the trap:

My issue is that all over copied files show always changes, regardless if there is a real content change, because of the line ending changes from CR LF -> LF

If I set `core.autocrlf=input` then no false changes after over copy, but if I edit (even adding a space) and save a file then undo the edit and save again, it automatically changes to CR LF (by my editors) so also seems as a change in git without no real content change...

**Question**

What would be the workflow to maintain this repo, and always keep commit changes clean, meaning only real content changes in file with clear diff information?

Answer (score 4):

`git config core.autocrlf false` remains the sensible option.

I usually add a .gitattributes, with, for instance:

```
*.bat   text eol=crlf
```

That way, the files are properly converted on `git commit`.

Since the `.gitattributes` file is part of the code base, it will be used by any user cloning the repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever turn on CRLF modification, Git will end up with a "preferred" internal encoding in which saved files have newline-only (LF-only) line endings, over time.

If you don't want this to happen, *and* want to keep all your files with CRLF line endings both *inside commits* and *when extracted from commits*, don't ever turn on any CRLF modification.  Whenever you get a file from somewhere else, modify it to have CRLF line endings *before* you ever let Git see it.

Otherwise, you'll want to make sure that Git itself stores all files with LF-only line endings, and arranges for text files—but not any other files—to have CRLF line endings when *extracted from* the repository.  To understand this at a high level, remember the following items:

- Every commit stores a full snapshot of every file.  However, these files are not in the same format that your computer uses.  Instead, they're compressed, Git-ified, and de-duplicated.  The de-duplication in particular is useful because many commits have mostly the same files as a previous commit, and this means Git only stores *one copy* of the file internally.
- This means each commit acts like an archive (a tar or zip file for instance).  The stuff that's inside any existing commit can never be changed: not even Git itself can change it.<sup>1</sup>  But this also means that none of your other computer programs can even *read* the file.  Literally nothing can *write* it and only Git can *read* it.  So the archives are only good *as* archives: you can't use them to get any *new* work done.
- Hence, to get *new* work done, Git has to *extract* the archived files.

It's the *extraction process* that will change LF-only line endings, as stored inside the commits, to CRLF line endings.  From now on, Git's files will be stored internally, in this compressed and de-duplicated form, as LF-only line endings.  (Any existing copies that have CRLF line endings cannot be changed and are therefore still CRLF endings, but *new* copies—not the re-used old ones, but newly added copies—will be LF-only.)

This is why turning CRLF modification on is disruptive: all the *existing* commits are, presumably, CRLF-only, and all *new* commits will prefer to save files as LF-only.  The new commits will re-use the old files if you have not touched the working tree file at all, but will *change* the files if you *have* touched the working tree file (because they'll strip the CR-s from the CRLF pairs).  You can choose to "rip the band-aid off all at once" (re-add every file, with `git add --renormalize` or similar) or let it happen over time, but one way or another Git will keep thinking you changed *every line of every file*, because you *will* do that.

Let me pause for the footnote, and then get into specifics.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for this has to do with the way Git stores the file data internally, representing it as a hash ID.  If anything changes, the hash ID changes too, so this is now a new, additional file: the old file is *still there*, with its old hash ID.

---

#### Specifics

> I thought `core.autocrlf=true` will work for me ...

It *can*.  I personally think this is a bad idea, because the "auto" part of this means *please guess about which file are text and which are not*.  I don't like my software to *guess*.  Git's gotten pretty good at guessing over the years, but it can still guess wrong now and then.

> ... If I set `core.autocrlf=input` ...

From a high-level point of view, again, we need to remember that the commits are Git-ified, and whenever Git is doing CRLF line whacking, Git will tend to *store* files as LF-only.  But it's time here to talk low-level rather than high-level.

There are two critical steps here:

- Extracting a commit: Here, Git has to read the *committed* files (in the Git-only, read-only, compressed-and-de-duplicated form).  These files aren't normal files at all.  It's easy for Git to replace LF-only with CRLF while doing this expansion.

  The result of expansion is your working tree copy: an ordinary file, that your computer can actually use.  These are the files your programs will see.  Note that this step occurs during, e.g., `git checkout` or `git reset --hard` when putting a file back to the way it is found inside a commit.
- Compressing a file to get it ready to store into a new commit.  Here, Git has to read the *working tree copy* of the file.  Git has to compress it down and check to see if it's a duplicate.  The compression stage is already checking the file byte by byte, so it's easy for Git to replace CRLF with LF-only during this step.

  The result of compressing is either a duplicate (complete with CRLF line endings, if Git didn't f— with them *and* the working tree copy *had* CRLF line endings, or LF-only line endings if Git did), or it's an all new file.  If it's a duplicate, Git links to the existing copy.  If it's all-new, Git stores it away, ready to be committed.

  Note that this step occurs during `git add`.  There's very little other than `git add` that re-compresses a file.<sup>2</sup>  But if you run `git add` on a file that you *have not touched* since you checked it out, Git will notice that you have not touched it, and will often skip the re-compression step.  So you have to defeat this optimization with `--renormalize`, or touch the file, to get Git to really re-compress.

The only time Git actually *does* mess with line endings is during either of these steps.  Using `input` as a setting tells Git: ***Don't** do the LF-to-CRLF during extraction, but **do** do the CRLF-to-LF during compression.*  This is only useful if you intend all *stored* Git files to be LF-only forever, and all *checked-out* files to stay LF-only: in other words, it **lets you see if there are committed files that have CRLF endings**, as they'll wind up with CRLF endings in your working tree.

Instead of any of the `auto` settings, you can use `.gitattributes` controls to tell Git *which files to f— with* and *what to do when it does that*.  The settings here are a bit finer-grained:

```
*.sh text eol=lf
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.jpg -text    # or binary
```

for instance tells Git that files named with `.sh` endings are to be messed with (are text), and should have LF-only line endings: Git will do the messing-with during `git add`, but do nothing during `git checkout`.  Meanwhile files with `.bat` endings are to be messed with and should have both extract and add steps get messed-with, so that the working tree copies have CRLF line endings but the committed copies have LF-only line endings, and `*.jpg` files should never be messed with.

The various `auto` settings mean: *Git, please guess which files are text and which ones are binary, and use the OS to decide how to mess with text files*.  Leaving out `.gitattributes` and *not* setting the `auto` settings (or setting them to `false`) means *Git, don't mess with my files!*

---

<sup>2</sup>There are some low-level plumbing commands, such as `git hash-file`, that can do it too.